# Encoding string to json

Tags: php, mysql, json, google-visualization

I' ve got a problem with encoding string to json. I'm doing a google pie chart. Chart will be filled with data from database. Google chart requires data in json format.

Below is the example of a string how it supposed to look like. Now I have a problem with dynamically "assembling" the string with data from database.
JSON_encode is not enough, it has to be in format like this string with cols and rows!
Please help.

```
<?php 

 $db=new DB();
 $db->connect();
 $db->selectBase();

 $rows = array();
 $sth=$db->st_glede_na_tip() or die(mysql_error());
 while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($sth)) {
     $rows[] = $r;
}


 $string= '{
     "cols": [
        {"id":"","label":"Content","pattern":"","type":"string"},
        {"id":"","label":"Slices","pattern":"","type":"number"}
       ],
    "rows": [
        {"c":[{"v":"Books"},{"v":3}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Video"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Audio"},{"v":1}]},
        {"c":[{"v":"Movie"},{"v":1}]},
      ]
   }';

   echo $string;


 ?>
```

Comment: you could use json_encode() function...?

Comment: Whats wrong with `json_encode` ???

Comment: Google charts requires unique format with cols and rows.

Comment: `json_encode` can encode any PHP **data structure** to the equivalent JSON/Javascript data structure. Your "special cols and rows" format is just a nested JSON array. You can create the same array structure using a PHP array, then `json_encode` that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing your problem is not knowing how to generate such a JS object from a PHP object.
You need to create a PHP array as such and then use the json_encode function :

```
$data = array(
    'cols' => array(
        array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Content', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'string'),
        array('id' => '', 'label' => 'Slices', 'pattern' => '', 'type' => 'number')     
    ),
    'rows' => array(
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Books'),
            array('v' => 3)         
        )), 
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Video'),
            array('v' => 1)         
        )),     
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Audio'),
            array('v' => 1)         
        )),     
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Movie'),
            array('v' => 1)         
        ))      
    )   
);  

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: thanks for that. But how would I get data from database into that array?

Comment: i don't know your database structure so that's an entirely different matter and it's yours!