# PHP + OBJ C Json encode strings

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I have to `encode` string in `PHP` using `JSON`. And I have a problem with finding anywhere examples of encoding strings. Everybody encodes arrays. Do you have any example of this in PHP and in obj c of decoding?

Comment: Did you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500366/encoding-string-to-json)?

Comment: Yes but it's array in this string

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking when you want to json encode something in PHP, you can use `json_encode`. Your root object must be an array (or dictionary) in order to produce a valid json string.
Note also that `json_encode` doesn't complain when you use it directly with strings (but it doesn't produce a valid json string).

```
echo json_encode(array('a' => 'test1', 'b' => 'test2'));
// {"a":"test1","b":"test2"}

echo json_encode(array('c'));
// ["c"]

echo json_encode('d');
// "d"
```

Objective-c code

```
// Let's assume that jsonString is a NSString containing {"a":"test1","b":"test2"}
NSData *data = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:&error];
NSLog(@"dictionary string: %@", dictionary[@"a"]); // Output: test1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried this one .

```
<?php

  $stringSingleElement = new array($yourstringdata) ;


 json_encode(stringSingleElement[0]);

?>
```

Comment: Hi , mickey how about trying place that string into a single element of an array then access it like $thatarray[0] thing ..?